# How can I enter angle brackets into an HTML form textbox so they won't be 'sanitized' away

Tags: html, escaping, sanitization

No, I am not trying to do anything evil.

There is a discussion website that I frequent that uses a textbox similar to what I am typing in now except that it had no accommodations to click for italics, bold, etc.  People figured out that you could just add the html tags to the text being submitted and things would be formatted correctly.  Then some people abused the system and started inserting IMG tags and such.

The response of the website was to use a meat cleaver instead of scalpel.  They seem to pre-process and strip *anything* with angle brackets.  This not only excludes the html tags that bugged them but *every* html code including new paragraphs.  So now every submission just looks like a massive slab of text without any formatting at all.  It is clear that they are just blindly stripping anything within angle brackets because even something like

```
It is nice <to see you> today.
```

ends up being

```
It is nice today.
```

So my question is: is there a way to escape the angle brackets so they get passed the pre-processing attempts.  IOW they are doing something like:

```
if (char == '<')
```

I would like something like "\asciicode" that would get past the censor module but be interpreted correctly by whatever used to normally interpret the html after that.

Again, I just want my NEWLINES back!

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with programming at all. Could you clarify?

Comment: I don't have any strict coding justification I would want to bring to the Hague but it seems to a question in the general area of input sanitizing and programming concepts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to change < to `&lt;` and > to `&gt;`

Also, " to `&quot;` and & to `&amp;`

Comment: So "<P>" would be "&ltP&gt" and "</P>" would be "&lt/P&gt"?

Comment: Another option would be to wrap that text in <pre> tags.  So <P>some text</P> could be <pre><P>some text</P></pre>

Comment: Ah, close but no cigar.  It gets turned into and printed as "<P>Hello World</P>".  I may be wrong about what they are doing and just plain SOL.

Comment: @Translucent You are correct, many sites do not code this part very well. But on the other hand they have to do something for some minimal protection against hacking their servers. A well coded form would accept the angle brackets and convert them to the encoded form internally, so you won't notice. But the http, html and browser standards, which are far from perfect, make this not a simple tasks. That's why not so many sites get it right.